# How to use alternationindex on code behind wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I have Itemcontrol in WPF. And Items source using Binding property.Items are only one button
How can I show index of item when I clicked Button? I read about AlternationIndex but only show on the xaml page.

Comment: Please help me. I tried 4 days.

Comment: You **need** to add your code to your question and be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it via Tag property.

```
    <ItemsControl AlternationCount="10">
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <Button Tag="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Tag="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Tag="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Tag="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Tag="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then you can parse it in Click handler.

```
//UserControl.xaml.cs
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    var alternationIndex = (int)Button.Tag;
}
```